# I am having a problem with intelliJ not finding the imports

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am having a problem with IntelliJ not finding the imports (and subsequently the classes)

At the moment the code is bare bones and doesn't do anything, I am in the process of practicing my skills but I can't get past this error.

The IntelliJ project can be found on [GitHub here](https://github.com/jareid/SpringPractice)

The code in question is MovieRecommenderSystemApplicationTests.java

```
package com.jreid.spring.basics.movierecommendersystem;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class MovieRecommenderSystemApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

And the errors are as follows:

```
java: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
java: package org.springframework.boot.test.context does not exist
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SpringBootTest
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class com.jreid.spring.basics.movierecommendersystem.MovieRecommenderSystemApplicationTests
```

IntelliJ finds the symbols without any problems.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try taking the <scope>test</scope> out as an experiment.

Comment: Same result unfortunately.

Comment: FWIW I imported the project to Eclipse and works great. Maybe Intelli project settings.

Comment: I'm not the biggest fan of Eclipse, I also had a problem when I tried it on Eclipse and I couldn't find the main class when trying to run as a Java Application (likely due to not using Eclipse for such a long time)
I guess I need an IntelliJ expert

Comment: This is what I get in Eclipse: Error: Could not find or load main class com.jreid.spring.basics.movierecommendersystem.withbeans.MovieRecommenderSystem.class  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jreid.spring.basics.movierecommendersystem.withbeans.MovieRecommenderSystem.class

Comment: Project setup - can’t find class files. Try Project >> clean

Comment: I'm getting 404 for the repo in question. Make sure it is not a private repository

Answer (score 0):

Enable auto import for maven dependency in settings `Import Maven projects automatically`. And do `mvn clean install`. If it won't work, use `Invalidate Caches` menu to reindex mvn repository.
And be sure you have all dependencies in pom.xml of course

Comment: Setting is enabled, as I said the IDE detects the imports as they are not highlighted with an error. The problem arises only when building. Did you check the project on Github?

Comment: there is no project now. And your title question is `intelliJ not finding the imports`. So the problem is not in ide. Problem is in your maven repository

Comment: The problem is Intellij in most cases when the local mvn clean install build runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

My remedy to the solution when intellij does not find jupiter or Q* objects (generated and compiled from another project):

1. Exit Intellij
2. mvn clean install -> must be successfull
3. start Intellij
4. Open Maven register (on my screen the right side)
5. Select Profiles on the top of the list
6. press the button "Reload all maven projects"
7. wait, then try to start the spring boot service
   ..
   in some cases this still does not work, then I do the same again, and very often this helps

Build,execution,deployment.build tools.reload project after changes in the build script.enabled
Build,execution,deployment.build tools.maven.execute goals recursively.enabled
Build,execution,deployment.build tools.maven.use settings from mvn/config.enabled
Build,execution,deployment.build tools.maven.runner.Delegate IDE buildrun actions to Maven.DISabled
Build,execution,deployment.build tools.maven.runner.Run in background.enabled
Build,execution,deployment.build tools.maven.runner.Skip Tests.DISabled